# Call Fragment/Activity from onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have 3 Fragments in a Activity like `splashscreen`, `login` and `register`. My LoginFragment based on asynctask.

So how can I call registerfragment from onPostExecute() in the LoginFragment, after the login process has been done ?

Help me.

Code Snippet:

```
protected void onPostExecute(httpresponse reesponse) {
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
super.onPostExecute(response);



// here the fragment must be called but how???
```

}

Comment: Thanks all I've solve the problemmFragmentCallbacks.onFragmentFinished(fragmentname.this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem that is...

```
 mFragmentCallbacks.onFragmentFinished(fragmentname.this);
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Can you let this above message show as a answer please..because I 've solved the prob..
Thanks